# Is there any way to create UDF for clickhouse?

Tags: clickhouse

In answer to a github ticket regarding UDF of clickhouse, they answered in 2017 that UDF can't be created in clickhouse. I want to know Is there any way to do it now in 2020?

Comment: At this moment UDF (user-defined functions) have not supported - see the reasons and actual discussions about it [UDF support #11](https://github.com/ClickHouse/ClickHouse/issues/11).

Comment: One workaround is to use executable dictionary source https://clickhouse.tech/docs/en/sql-reference/dictionaries/external-dictionaries/external-dicts-dict-sources/#dicts-external_dicts_dict_sources-executable. It is available since 21.3 release. You can create executable file, and call it as dictionary.

Comment: + look at this one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71236415/how-to-send-multiple-arguments-to-executable-udf-in-clickhouse

Answer (score 6):

UDFs for ClickHouse came in September, 2021. There are two PRs introducing UDFs:

- [UDF as an SQL expression](https://github.com/ClickHouse/ClickHouse/pull/27796), example: `CREATE FUNCTION plus_one as (a) -> a + 1`. I have tested this on ClickHouse v21.10.2.15 and it works (should be supported [starting from v21.10](https://github.com/ClickHouse/ClickHouse/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#new-feature)).
- [UDF as an executable script](https://github.com/ClickHouse/ClickHouse/pull/28803). Such a function is defined within ClickHouse server configuration, see an [example in the PR](https://github.com/ClickHouse/ClickHouse/pull/28803/files#diff-703a693d0949c66402bec668d9da6f08943c480950a4d8163cd38a515b4b1815R13). This is an arbitrary script that reads data from stdin and outputs data to stdout in a supported format: [CSV](https://clickhouse.com/docs/en/interfaces/formats/#csv), [TabSeparated](https://clickhouse.com/docs/en/interfaces/formats/#tabseparated), or [others](https://clickhouse.com/docs/en/interfaces/formats/). The example uses [`clickhouse-local`](https://clickhouse.com/docs/en/operations/utilities/clickhouse-local/) to process data incoming from ClickHouse server.

As a [presentation from 2021](https://presentations.clickhouse.com/meetup50/new_features/index.html#20) says, ClickHouse team considers five ways to define a UDF. One of alternative ways mentioned [in an older presentation](https://presentations.clickhouse.com/highload_spb_2020/#35) is a [cache dictionary](https://clickhouse.com/docs/en/sql-reference/dictionaries/external-dictionaries/external-dicts-dict-layout/#cache) with an [executable source](https://clickhouse.com/docs/en/sql-reference/dictionaries/external-dictionaries/external-dicts-dict-sources/#dicts-external_dicts_dict_sources-executable).