# How to send multiple arguments to Executable UDF in ClickHouse?

Tags: python, clickhouse

I've a python script that outputs the input:

```py
#!/usr/bin/python3

import sys

if __name__ == '__main__':
    i = 0
    for line in sys.stdin:
        print(i, line, end='')
        sys.stdout.flush()
        i += 1
```

This script is connected to ClickHouse with this config:

```xml
<functions>
    <function>
        <type>executable</type>
        <name>test_function_python</name>
        <return_type>String</return_type>
        <argument><type>Int64</type></argument>
        <format>TabSeparated</format>
        <command>test_function.py</command>
        <execute_direct>1</execute_direct>
    </function>
</functions>
```

The script is called from ClickHouse:

```sh
SELECT test_function_python(number) AS x        
FROM numbers(5)                                 
                                                
                                                
┌─x───┐                                         
│ 0 0 │                                         
│ 1 1 │                                         
│ 2 2 │                                         
│ 3 3 │                                         
│ 4 4 │                                         
└─────┘
```

So far so good but I want to send multiple parameters to the UDF like this:

```sh
SELECT test_function_python(number, number + 3) AS x        
FROM numbers(5)
```

So how do I get two arguments from Python code??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use multiple `<argument>` tag in function config (`python_function.xml` in `/etc/clickhouse-server`:

```xml
<functions>                                     
    <function>                                  
        <type>executable</type>                 
        <name>test_function_python</name>       
        <return_type>String</return_type>       
        <argument><type>String</type></argument>
        <argument><type>String</type></argument>
        <format>TabSeparated</format>           
        <command>test_function.py</command>     
        <execute_direct>1</execute_direct>      
    </function>                                 
</functions>
```

Then pass two arguments to python function:

```sql
SELECT test_function_python(number, number + 1) AS x   
FROM numbers(10)                                       
                                                       
Query id: 562676d4-e7fb-4aec-86b4-fef41fec4864         
                                                       
┌─x─────────────────┐                                  
│ 0: arg1=0 arg2=1  │                                  
│ 1: arg1=1 arg2=2  │                                  
│ 2: arg1=2 arg2=3  │                                  
│ 3: arg1=3 arg2=4  │                                  
│ 4: arg1=4 arg2=5  │                                  
│ 5: arg1=5 arg2=6  │                                  
│ 6: arg1=6 arg2=7  │                                  
│ 7: arg1=7 arg2=8  │                                  
│ 8: arg1=8 arg2=9  │                                  
│ 9: arg1=9 arg2=10 │                                  
└───────────────────┘
```

Python code (`test_function.py`):

```py
#!/usr/bin/python3

import sys

if __name__ == '__main__':
    i = 0
    for line in sys.stdin:
        arg1, arg2 = line.split('\t')
        print(f'{i}: arg1={arg1} arg2={arg2}', end='')
        sys.stdout.flush()
        i += 1
```

Comment: Actually, I was asking about how to catch 2 parameters in Python code.

Comment: when you define <format>TabSeparated</format>
each sys.stdin line in python will serialized as TabSeparated
you need just parse stdin as TabSeparated and split input values by "\t"
look details here https://github.com/ClickHouse/ClickHouse/tree/master/tests/integration/test_executable_user_defined_function

Comment: if <format> parameter the format of input to python script, or format of output?

Comment: I think it <format> is both for input and output