# how to defined Executable User Defined Function in ClickHouse?

Tags: clickhouse

According to the [ClickHouse documentation](https://clickhouse.com/docs/en/sql-reference/functions/#executable-user-defined-functions), I want to define a Executable User Defined Function.

how to connect above script to ClickHouse? In which directory should I copy the Python and XML file?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to send multiple arguments to Executable UDF in ClickHouse?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71236415/how-to-send-multiple-arguments-to-executable-udf-in-clickhouse)

Comment: Thanks for the reply @vladimir . I don't know which directory to copy the Python file and the XML file. I also want to know if I need to change the config.xmi file?

Answer (score 0):

Follow the steps to create a Sample UDF in clickhouse.

1. `cd /etc/clickhouse-server`
2. Create a function with the name `test_function.xml`. You can name the file anything, but make sure it ends with _function.xml.
3. Add the following lines in the test_function.xml file-

```
<functions>
    <function>
        <type>executable</type>
        <name>test_function_python</name>
        <return_type>String</return_type>
        <argument>
            <type>UInt64</type>
            <name>value</name>
        </argument>
        <format>TabSeparated</format>
        <command>test_function.py</command>
    </function>
</functions>
```

4. cd into `/var/lib/clickhouse/user_scripts/`
5. Create a file `test_function.py`
6. Add the following lines in the file-

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

import sys

if __name__ == '__main__':
    for line in sys.stdin:
        print("Value " + line, end='')
        sys.stdout.flush()
```

7. Enter into clickhouse-client using `clickhouse-client` command
8. To verify if your function is reflecting, execute the following query-

```
select * from system.functions where origin=2
```

9. If you find your function, you can start using it in your sql statements.